# How to show the states data (in the form of Checkboxes) after selecting country from option list

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

There are 3 dropdown listboxes.
1.Country 2. States 3. City

It works fine in dropdown list style but i want that,

when i select an option from
the country, the states should be shown in the form of checkboxes.
I tried my best but i dont know why it doest shown in the form of checkboxes.

"sorry for my English"

ajaxData.php

```
<?php
//Include database configuration file
include('dbConfig.php');

if(isset($_POST["country_id"]) && !empty($_POST["country_id"])){
//Get all state data
$query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM states WHERE country_id = 
".$_POST['country_id']."");

//Count total number of rows
$rowCount = $query->num_rows;

//Display states list
if($rowCount > 0){
    echo '<input type ="checkbox" value="">'Select state ;
    while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()){

        echo '<input type="checkbox" 
value="'.$row['state_id'].'">'.$row['state_name'].'';
    }
}else{
    echo '<input type="checkbox" value="">'State not available;
}
}

if(isset($_POST["state_id"]) && !empty($_POST["state_id"])){
//Get all city data
$query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM cities WHERE state_id = 
".$_POST['state_id']."");

//Count total number of rows
$rowCount = $query->num_rows;

//Display cities list
if($rowCount > 0){
    echo '<option value="">Select city</option>';
    while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()){
        echo '<option 
 value="'.$row['city_id'].'">'.$row['city_name'].'</option>';
    }
}else{
    echo '<option value="">City not available</option>';
}
}
?>
```

the 2nd file is

index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title></title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css.css">
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open 
 Sans">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font- 
 awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" 
 href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
 <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
 <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
 <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>

 <style>
 h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6 {font-family: "Oswald"}
 body {font-family: "Open Sans"}


 .select-boxes{width: 280px;text-align: center;}
  select {
background-color: #F5F5F5;
border: 1px double #15a6c7;
color: #1d93d1;
font-family: Georgia;
font-weight: bold;
font-size: 14px;
height: 39px;
padding: 7px 8px;
width: 250px;
outline: none;
margin: 10px 0 10px 0;
}
select option{
font-family: Georgia;
font-size: 14px;
}
</style>
//---------------------------AJAX Technique --------------------------------- 
-----//

 <script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){
 // ---------------------------------------------- 1 ------------------------ 
  ----------------------
   $('#country').on('change',function(){
    var countryID = $(this).val();
    if(countryID){
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'ajaxData.php',
            data:'country_id='+countryID,
            success:function(html){

                $('#state').html(html);
                $('#city').html('<option value="">Select state 
 first</option>');
            }
        });
    }else{
        $('#state').html('<option value="">Select country first</option>');
        $('#city').html('<option value="">Select state first</option>');
    }
   });

    $('#state').on('change',function(){
    var stateID = $(this).val();
    if(stateID){
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'ajaxData.php',
            data:'state_id='+stateID,
            success:function(html){
                $('#city').html(html);
            }
        });
    }else{
        $('#city').html('<option value="">Select state first</option>');
    }
    });
    });
    </script>
    //------------------------------------AJAX Technique END----------------- 
    -----------------------------//

  <body class="w3-light-grey">

  <!-- Navigation bar with social media icons -->
  <div class="w3-bar w3-black w3-hide-small">
  <a href="https://www.facebook.com/lisenme/" class="w3-bar-item w3-button"> 
  <i class="fa fa-facebook-official"></i></a>
   <a href="https://twitter.com/LisenMee" class="w3-bar-item w3-button"><i 
   class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
   <a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCEdC6Qk_DZ9fX_gUYFJ1tsA" 
   class="w3-bar-item w3-button"><i class="fa fa-youtube"></i></a>
       <a href="https://plus.google.com/115714479889692934329" class="w3-bar- 
    item w3-button"><i class="fa fa-google"></i></a>



      <div class="w3-content" style="max-width:1600px">

  <h6>Welcome to our <span class="w3-tag">Tutorial</span></h6>

  </header>

  <!-- Image header -->


 <!-- Grid -->
 <div class="w3-row w3-padding w3-border">

<!-- Blog entries -->
<div class="w3-col l12 s12">

  <!-- Blog entry -->
  <div class="w3-container w3-white w3-margin w3-padding-large">

      <h2 style="text-align: center";>Dynamic Dependent Select Box using 
      jQuery, Ajax and PHP</h2>
      <br>
      <div class="select-boxes">
<?php
//Include database configuration file
include('dbConfig.php');

//Get all country data
$query = "SELECT * FROM countries";
$rowCount= mysqli_query($db,$query);

//Count total number of rows
// $rowCount =mysqli_num_rows($result);
// $rowCount = $query->num_rows;
?>
<!------------------------ 1 ----------------------------- -->
<select name="country" id="country" >
    <option value="">Select Country</option>
    <?php
    if (mysqli_num_rows($rowCount) > 0) {
      while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rowCount)) {
            echo '<option 
    value="'.$row['country_id'].'">'.$row['country_name'].'</option>';
        }
    }else{
        echo '<option value="">Country not available</option>';
    }
    ?>
 </select> </ br>
  <!-------- 2 ----------------------- -->
 <input type="checkbox" name="state" id="state"  value="">
  <!--  <option value="">Select country first</option> -->
 </select>
 <!---------------------------------- 3 --------------------------- -->
 <select name="city" id="city">
    <option value="">Select state first</option>
 </select>
 </div>



  </div>

  </div>

 </div>

 </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: why you are using Procedural and oops together use only one method either Procedural or oops

Comment: ok, I will use procedural but the problem still remains. solution?